# How to avoid hard coding the server url

Tags: javascript, webpack, angular

I am pretty new to the javascript world. I have an application with Angular2 + Webpack using Typescript and I want to define the url of my server inside a property file in order to be able to change it after the build.

It's like a config.js file accessible after the build and accessible in dev mode too.

First: is it a good idea?
Second: why am I feeling like I am the only one with this kind of problem?

If it is a good idea, how do you do this?

Comment: What is the end you're trying to achieve here? How do you intend to use the url? The answers to those questions might help answer your second question.

Comment: I want to use the url in order to consume a REST api using angular2 http.

Comment: So in short - as Aaron has sort of covered this in his answer, the reason it feels like you're the only one, is that it's quite not terribly that the client needs absolute URLs to your own back-end, because relative URLs do the job and are a lot less fragile. This matters more for consuming another party's APIs. In Angular 1.x I might set up an Angular service that handles all calls to that 3rd party API and can easily contain a constant for the URL. I've not done Angular 2, but from what I can see it looks like the same approach is still valid. And then inject it into components that need it.

Comment: the problem is the url change depending the environement (dev, prod..)

Comment: Just the host/domain? Or other parts of the path?

Comment: You get that for free with relative URLs - assuming your front-end app is being served from the same host that the API lives on.

Comment: So if my Angular app is serving from devhost:1234/index.html and it has an API call to "./items", this will call devhost:1234/items. If I pick up that same Angular app and host it on prodhost:8080, without changing anything the same call will be to prodhost:8080/items.

Comment: I want to be able to use dev1:1234/api and dev2:4567/api2 : I have 2 or more hosts for the same environment and they differ from an env from another.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have one host, that is all your content is served from the same server or your backend server is accessible through the same domain name and port than your frontend server, you should use [relative URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Understanding_URLs#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs).

Comment: I may have more than one host in the future. At the moment, relative urls should be enough but I am looking forward for future problems.

Comment: @bobkilla I don't know angular2 but in angular I think I would have used a [module value](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#value-recipe). I don't know webpack either, so I might very well be missing a more appropriate way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely it is a good idea, and no, this is not a problem.

Typically you would define a default config and subsequent ENV specific config that may/not override the default.  A common way of doing this is to set an ENV variable that your application can process and choose the ENV specific config.

Have a look at MEAN.io and their seed project, they do elegantly.

Webpack can detect the changes and reload the application.  Obviously not something you want to do in PROD